# Confused with floats and ints

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point, int

They're not the best of friends.

I have this:

```
int svNumberOfObjects = 9;
```

and this:

```
int svColumns = 4;
```

and then there's also this:

```
float numberOfRows = svNumberOfObjects/svColumns;
```

which comes out with this:

> 2.000000

How can i get it to show me the actual float value?

Comment: The issue is that the two ints are being divided with integer division. Usually in C/C++ we work around this by casting one of the ints as a float. I don't know any Obj-C syntax for casting so I'll refrain from answering.

Comment: @ProdigySim: Objective-C is identical to C except in the ways that it's different =).  Specifically, all C code is valid Objective-C, so explicit casts are exactly the same in both languages.

Comment: @ProdigySim: Like C++, Objective-C started out as a set of C macros. It still has C as a subset, like C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
float numberOfRows = (float)svNumberOfObjects/svColumns;
```

Your code at present uses *integer* division, which truncates the result to an integer.  You want a floating-point division instead, which means that you need one of the operands to be a floating-point value; the explicit cast accomplishes this.

Answer (score 2):

```
float numberOfRows = (float)svNumberOfObjects/svColumns;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
float numberOfRows = 1.0*svNumberOfObjects/svColumns;
```

Comment: let me be the first to say, euww! Cast is much better.

Comment: I don't claim it's pretty, but it's always an option. Just like with gotos: even though it's generally discouraged, every book on C mentions it ;)